# When does an Activity receive broadcast in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Concerning Broadcast Receiver running inside an Activity. Normally I register inside onResume and unregister inside onPause. But. Say my Activity was paused when a sender sent a broadcast and now my activity is resumed. Will the Activity, now resumed, receive the broadcast?

Now understand this. The Docs say the Activity will not receive intent when paused. But the statement is dangling for my particular inquiry.

```
onCreate -> onResume -> onPause|...broadcast sent...| -> onResume-> ???
```

Comment: The primary reason for unregistering a Receiver in `onPause()` is because you're not interested in receiving a broadcast while your Activity is inactive. If this isn't true, you should look into registering a receiver in a Service which runs in the background.

Comment: I like both answers and I will up vote both. But @adelphus yours goes a step further in suggesting pairing with a service and so I would like to check it as the best response if you post as a response. For people who don't understand, since the comment is a bit terse, my Activity would bind to the service and check for updates that way.

Comment: Appreciate it, but my comment doesn't actually answer your question (*Will the activity receive the broadcast"). Generally, SO likes you to mark the answer to your actual question, even if the comments help you out.

Comment: Very gentlemanly of you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because by the time you're sending the broadcast to that activity, you have already unregistered that receiver. Therefore, the broadcast will be sent, look for a receiver that can handle that broadcast, and since there is none, drop that request.

On resume, your app will re-register the receiver. However, since the previous request was dropped, it will not respond to it, but only to requests sent when the activity has resumed.